# MySQL : Select the rows having the max value for one field and keep correct values for joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I know there are a lot of already answered questions about this but I spent days to adapt the answers to my case and I can't manage to make it work. So please be kind and help me.

I do this query :

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.commit,
    b.id,
    c.value

FROM TableA a

INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.id_a = a.id
INNER JOIN TableB ON c.id_b = b.id
INNER JOIN TableD d ON a.id_d = d.id

WHERE a.commit <= 9000 AND a.id_s = 10 AND d.id_f = 1

ORDER BY b.custom_order, a.commit ASC
```

Below, the results of this query. I want to get only the rows that have the **greatest commit** for every **b.id** :

```
a.id | a.commit | b.id | c.value
--------------------------------
257  | 4000     | 11   | 33
258  | 6000     | 11   | 34
259  | 8000     | 11   | 35
257  | 4000     | 1    | 40
258  | 6000     | 1    | 40
259  | 8000     | 1    | 40
257  | 4000     | 2    | 40
258  | 6000     | 2    | 40
259  | 8000     | 2    | 40
257  | 4000     | 3    | 15
258  | 6000     | 3    | 25
259  | 8000     | 3    | 25
```

So, I want all the rows with commit = 8000 :

```
a.id | a.commit | b.id | c.value
--------------------------------
259  | 8000     | 11   | 35
259  | 8000     | 1    | 40
259  | 8000     | 2    | 40
259  | 8000     | 3    | 25
```

I found this solution below but I can't use it with Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine because **Doctrine can't do an inner join on a sub query**...

```
SELECT
    a1.id,
    a1.commit,
    b1.id,
    c1.value

FROM TableA a1

INNER JOIN TableC c1 ON c1.id_a = a1.id
INNER JOIN TableB ON c1.id_b = b1.id
INNER JOIN TableD d1 ON a1.id_d = d1.id

INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        b.id,
        MAX(a.commit) max_commit

    FROM TableA a

    INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.id_a = a.id
    INNER JOIN TableB ON c.id_b = b.id
    INNER JOIN TableD d ON a.id_d = d.id

    WHERE a.id_s = 10 AND a.commit <= 9000 AND d.id_f = 1

    GROUP BY b.id

) results ON b1.id = results.id AND a1.commit = results.max_commit

WHERE a1.id_s = 10

ORDER BY b1.custom_order ASC
```

Comment: Easy in MySQL 8.x, but not in 5.x. What version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: @TheImpaler MySQL server 8.0.16 but I use Doctrine with Symfony 3.4 to do the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Doctrine but you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to filter out the rows you don't want. For example:

```
SELECT
  a_id,
  commit,
  b_id,
  value
from (
  SELECT
    a.id as "a_id",
    a.commit,
    b.id as "b_id",
    c.value,
    b.custom_order,
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY a.commit DESC) as rn
  FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.id_a = a.id
  INNER JOIN TableB ON c.id_b = b.id
  INNER JOIN TableD d ON a.id_d = d.id
  WHERE a.commit <= 9000 AND a.id_s = 10 AND d.id_f = 1
) x
ORDER BY custom_order, commit ASC
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks it works on phpMyAdmin, just inverse the 2 last lines. But I don't know if I could do it with Doctrine. I have to check that.

Comment: As I expected, Doctrine can't do a `from` on a sub query (just like `inner join`) but we can do a `where id IN/NOT IN ()` clause. Do you think you can do the same that you wrote but with a `IN/NOT IN` ?